# aspose.cell csv reading with single quote as text qualifier and comma as column delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, csv, aspose-cells

I am using aspose.cell to read my csv file with "," as column delimiter & single quote (') as text qualifier & newline as row delimiter. Looks like below one:
ex:

'1'.'2','3','4'

'5','6','7','8'

while reading from aspose.cell, the values(considering all text values no numeric) are render like

1', 2', 3', 4'

5', 6', 7', 8'

There is no problem when Text Qualifier is double quote (").

**can somebody help one this, how to my csv file with single quote (') as text qualifier with aspose.cell**?

Thank you

```
TxtLoadOptions options = new TxtLoadOptions( LoadFormat.CSV)
options.ConvertNumericData = false;
options.ConvertDateTimeData = false;
options.SeparatorString=",";
//  reading aspose license reading, code removed
//stream    is ----stream reader
Workbook workBook = new Workbook(stream, options);
workBook.Settings.CheckExcelRestriction = false;
var workSheet = workBook.Worksheets[workBook.Worksheets.ActiveSheetIndex];

Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 0].Value.ToString());  
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 1].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 2].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 3].Value.ToString());

Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 0].Value.ToString());  
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 3].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue when using TxtLoadOptions with a CSV file. You can try using LoadOptions instead of TxtLoadOptions to open your csv file without any issue. You can refer to the below code:

```
Aspose.Cells.LoadOptions options = new Aspose.Cells.LoadOptions(Aspose.Cells.LoadFormat.CSV);

options.ConvertNumericData = false;

Workbook workBook = new Workbook("C:\\Data\\open.csv", options);
workBook.Settings.CheckExcelRestriction = false;
var workSheet = workBook.Worksheets[workBook.Worksheets.ActiveSheetIndex];

Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 0].Value.ToString());  
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 1].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 2].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[0, 3].Value.ToString());

Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 0].Value.ToString());  
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( workSheet.Cells[1, 3].Value.ToString());
```

Hope this helps.